# I can't get runit to work with chef and puma, it might be a runit issue but I'm not sure

Tags: ruby, automation, chef-infra, puma, runit

Here is the runit script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd <%= @options[:release_path] %>
exec 2>&1
exec chpst -u <%= @options[:owner] %>:<%= @options[:group] %> <%= @options[:puma_command] %> -C config/puma.rb
```

Here is the runit log script:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec chpst -u root:root svlogd -tt <%= @options[:log_dir] %>
```

Here is how I'm populating those variables in chef:

```
deploy_path = "/home/#{node[:myapp][:user]}/#{cookbook_name}"
shared_path = "#{deploy_path}/shared"
rvm_context = '/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm 2.1.0 do'

deploy_revision 'path/to/my/service' do
  restart_command do
    runit_service 'puma' do
      options(
        :release_path => "#{deploy_path}/current",
        :owner        => 'foo',
        :group        => 'foo',
        :puma_command => "#{rvm_context} bundle exec puma",
        :log_dir      => "#{shared_path}/log"
      )
    end
  end
end
```

Chef completes the run successfully but the service is not started.

If I run this command manually then I get a timeout error.

```
chef@cheftests:/etc/sv/puma$ sudo sv start puma
timeout: down: puma: 0s, normally up, want up
```

If I run the **exact** command that the `puma_command` populates the runit script with then puma successfully starts, at this point it's completely bypassing runit but I know for sure the puma script is in working order.

Comment: You're passing the runit_service resource to restart_command - where'd you get that idea?

I think you should use runit_service to set up the service, then pass a string like "sv restart puma" as the restart_command.

Comment: It's undocumented but it works like that. Someone who I thought was a trust worthy source in the chef IRC channel mentioned you can do that. He wouldn't say how to hook it all together tho. I guess it was too super secret for the world to know how to use chef/puma/runit together.

I have given up on using chef to manage puma/runit.